# How to Arranged expected new array from original array

Tags: php

When the value of the three keys (USERID, DATE, ITEM DETAIL) is the same in another index of an array, then we need to add the value of the QUANTITY, Please See the expected array below.
**Original array looks like:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-08'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 3.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-09'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 4.90
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-09'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 1.20
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-09'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Travel Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 4.40
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-09'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Travel Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 3.20
        )
)
```

Here : The value of the three keys (USERID, DATE, ITEM DETAIL) in Index 2 and Index 3 are the same, so SUM of QUANTITY keys value **like : 4.90+1.20**.

Similarly, three keys (USERID, DATE, ITEM DETAIL) in Index 3 and Index 4 are the same so the SUM of QUANTITY keys value **like 4.40 + 3.20**.

I want to create an expected array in this way. please, Can anyone help me?
The **Expected array looks like:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-08'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 3.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-09'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 5.10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => '2018-01-09'
            [ITEM DETAIL] => 'Claims Investigation Travel Hours'
            [QUANTITY] => 7.60
        )
)
```

Comment: Do this directly from SQL itself if this is coming from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved also with array reduce

```
$array = array_values(array_reduce($array, function($a, $b) {
    $key = implode("|", [$b['USERID'], $b['DATE'], $b['ITEM DETAIL']]);
    if(array_key_exists($key, $a)) {
        $a[$key]['QUANTITY']+= $b['QUANTITY'];
    } else {
        $a[$key] = $b;
    }

    return $a;
}, []));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
$final = [];

foreach ($arr as $a) {
    // generating a unique key based on the required conditions
    $key = $a['USER_ID'] . $a['DATE'] . $a['ITEM DETAIL'];
    // if not set for unique record then set the first record
    if (!isset($final[$key])) {
        $final[$key] = $a;
    } else {
        // increment the quantity for repeats 
        $final[$key]['QUANTITY'] += $a['QUANTITY'];
    }
}

$final = array_values($final);

print_r($final);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => 2018-01-08
            [ITEM DETAIL] => Claims Investigation Hours
            [QUANTITY] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => 2018-01-09
            [ITEM DETAIL] => Claims Investigation Hours
            [QUANTITY] => 6.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [USERID] => 63120
            [DATE] => 2018-01-09
            [ITEM DETAIL] => Claims Investigation Travel Hours
            [QUANTITY] => 7.6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet, please see inline doc for explanation

```
$result = [];
$i = 0;
array_multisort(array_column($arr,'USERID'), SORT_ASC, 
array_column($arr,'DATE'), SORT_ASC,array_column($arr,
'ITEM DETAIL'),SORT_ASC, $data);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($arr[$key + 1])) { // checking for last if not empty
        // checking your condition
        if ($arr[$key]['USERID'] == $arr[$key + 1]['USERID'] &&
            $arr[$key]['DATE'] == $arr[$key + 1]['DATE'] &&
            $arr[$key]['ITEM DETAIL'] == $arr[$key + 1]['ITEM DETAIL']) 
        {
            // assigning current value to result
            $result[$i] = $value;
            // add next value to current
            $result[$i]['QUANTITY'] += $arr[$key + 1]['QUANTITY'];
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: What if the order is random?

Comment: Then we can sort and then same procedure.

Comment: Yes. But for sorting we have to use `usort` with date, id, details all togather and process also.

Comment: Exactly. I Have to.